# ¿Cómo puedo almacenar String en la Clase que cree?

Tags: java, java-swing

### En el Método `Ncheck` no me almacena los String.

No me almacena los valores tipo String Si llamo el método `setNomb();` desde en el método `Ncheck()`, Estado batallando y no se que hago mal, si lo llamo desde afuera si puedo almacenar no se si me explico bien soy autodidacta en esto de la programación, así que disculpen si cometo errores en el código o en la publicación de esta pagina.

```
public class Cuenta{
protected int fecha;
protected String s;
protected ArrayList<Integer>ListNc = new ArrayList<>();
protected ArrayList<String>ListNc2 = new ArrayList<>();


public Cuenta(){
   ListNc.add(190201);
   ListNc.add(190619);
   ListNc.add(190816);
   
   ListNc2.add("Jorge");
   ListNc2.add("Juan");
   ListNc2.add("Pedro");
}    
}

class Check extends Cuenta{
    private int CkNcuenta; // /*Variable para chequear cuenta*/

private boolean VCuenta; /*Variable para confirmar si esta bien el # de cuenta*/
private String Nombre;
 

public Check(){
    this.CkNcuenta = 0; 
    this.VCuenta = false;
    this.Nombre = null;
    
}
//----------------- Chequea el numero de cuenta -------------------------//
public void Ncheck(){
    boolean v;
    for(int i = 0; i < ListNc.size(); i++){
        if(this.getNc() == ListNc.get(i)){
            this.setV(v = true);
            break;
        }
        else{
            this.setV(v = false);
        }
    }
}
//----------------- Agrega Verdadero o Falso a la variable VCuenta -------------------------
public void setV(boolean v){
    this.VCuenta = v;
}
   
// ------------------ Toma el valor de la variable booleano VCuenta------------------------
public boolean getV(){
    return VCuenta;
}
 
public void setNomb(String x){
    this.Nombre = x;
}

public String getNomb(){
     
    return Nombre;
}
// ------------------ agrega el # de cuenta de la caja de texto a la variabel nCuenta --------------
public void setNc(int x){
    this.CkNcuenta = x;
}

// ----------------------- Toma el # de cuenta guardado en la variable nCuenta --------------------- 
public int getNc(){
    return CkNcuenta;
}

}
```

Comment: Pero en el método Ncheck() no estás llamando al método setNomb()

Comment: Me lo he leido varias veces y sigo sin entender que es lo que pretendes. Intenta explicarte un poco mejor.

Comment: Sí, necesitamos más información.  De dónde llama su clase?  Debe ser Nombre almacenado por siempre (como en un base de datos?)  Además, this.setV(v = true) y this.setV(v = false) ambos ponen true en VCuenta porque = no es comparación.

Comment: Hola @JorgeHernandez deseas agregar propiedades al objeto en este caso mediante setNomb(), para esto debes instanciar el objeto y puedes definir todas las propiedades mediante los setters del objeto Check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te sugiero revisar [**Conceptos de programación orientada a objetos**](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ssa/java/tutorials/j-introtojava1/index.html)

En este caso tratas de llamar `SetNomb()`, e implica que deseas agregar un valor a la propiedad `Nombre` del objeto

```
public void setNomb(String x){
    this.Nombre = x;
}
```

Lo que debes realizar para agregar propiedades al objeto es crear una instancia del objeto y definir valores a sus propiedades mediante los setters :

```
   Check c = new Check(); //Crea objeto
    c.setNc(190201);  //Agrega propiedad.
    c.setNomb("Jorge"); //Agrega propiedad.
    c.setV(true);  //Agrega propiedad.
```

Ahora para almacenar varios objetos con sus propiedades puedes crear una lista de objetos tipo `Check`:

```
   protected List<Check>ListNChecks = new ArrayList<Check>();
```

---

Este seria el código para crear los objetos, con sus propiedades y agregarlos en un listado:

```
  protected List<Check>ListNChecks = new ArrayList<Check>();

  public Cuenta() {

        Check c = new Check(); //Crea objeto
        c.setNc(190201);  //Agrega propiedad.
        c.setNomb("Jorge"); //Agrega propiedad.
        c.setV(true);  //Agrega propiedad.
        ListNChecks.add(c);  //Agrega objecto a la lista

        c = new Check(); //Agrega propiedad.
        c.setNomb("Juan");  //Agrega propiedad. 
        c.setNc(190619);  //Agrega propiedad.
        c.setV(true);   //Agrega propiedad.
        ListNChecks.add(c); //Agrega objecto a la lista

        c = new Check();  //Crea objeto
        c.setNomb("Pedro");  //Agrega propiedad.
        c.setNc(190816);  //Agrega propiedad.
        c.setV(true);  //Agrega propiedad.
        ListNChecks.add(c);  //Agrega objecto a la lista


    }
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias pude resolver mi problema.

Comment: @JorgeHernandez un placer ayudarte, no necesitas crear listas de propiedades, crea un objeto con sus propiedades, revisa lo relacionado a Programación Orientada a objetos, saludos!